# Why are not all modules imported, but can still be used?

Tags: python, import, module, kivy, boxlayout

I don't have any struggle with any code or similar, but I wonder, why don't we always have to import everything we use (like for example BoxLayout or GridLayout)? I can use a BoxLayout even without importing it, so my question is: When is it mandatory to import a module and when isn't it really necessary? I couldn't find anything about it on the internet so I thought I could get some information here.

Comment: I don't think that's true or maybe You are using 2 or more py file for your app and in one of them you have imported the module

Answer (score 1):

The reason you could use classes like `BoxLayout` and `GridLayout` even without explicitly importing them is because they are parts of the library anyway.

As for your question on when is it necessary to explicitly import libraries, I think it's a good programming practice to always do so. This way, you'll be able to avoid confusion in referring to classes or functions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, though I was rather looking for a concrete answer about it. In a tutorial both layouts were used and only the gridlayout was imported.  I would like to have some solid imagination of when it is required and when it's rather optional